# Read yaml file from s3 bucket path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to read a yaml file that is located in a subfolder of a folder in an s3 bucket without iterating over the contents?
An example path for a yaml file would look like `s3://bucket/folder/sub/file.yml`.
There is a [solution](https://gist.github.com/coingraham/c6153809e4d179396421) for yaml files in a bucket but without the option to access the subfolders

```
bucket = "bucket"
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key="file.yml")
configfile = yaml.safe_load(response["Body"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you would just specify all the subfolders in the `Key` parameter:

```py
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key="folder/sub/file.yml")
```

Comment: i have tried setting the path in the key but this would return the error `botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.`

Comment: @Blob can you update your question with the exact `get_object` call you're making?

Are you absolutely certain that the path and file exists? Is there any encryption or resource policies applied?